# How to generate a logging variable obtained from a function in a class?

Tags: php, logging, compiler-errors

I'm trying to add logging to my project, and I get loggers using a registry lookup (e.g. with `$logger = LoggerRegistry::get('general');`). I am wondering how to generate and store such a variable sensibly inside a class.

I'd ideally like each class to contain a variable $logger (ideally static and final/const) which is set in the same line it is declared, but I get the fatal error "Constant expression contains invalid operations".

```
class Foo
{
    $logger = LoggerRegistry::get('general'); /* Fatal error: Constant expression contains invalid operations */

    public function bar()
    {
        doThing();
        self::$logger->log('');
    }
}
```

This method gives a "Constant expression contains invalid operations". I understand this is because I am trying to set a static value equal to a function that cannot be determined at compile time. But by the time the class is used, or even mentioned, the value has been set.

Is there a good workaround to the problem? How is logging typically achieved in PHP, in practice?

I ideally do not want to forego the registry as I feel it too-tightly couples the logging and classes using logging, but it does problematically introduce the function giving rise to the fatal problem. It seems excessive to have a new reference for each instance. And including an `__init__()` function or similar, that is called immediately after the class is declared, seems a bit unnecessary. But I may add this such that my autoloading automatically calls any `__init__` function a class may have, if it has one.

Comment: `.` is php __concatenation__ operator. Are you sure you should use it?

Comment: Ah yes, a mistype.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A static property cannot be set equal to an object as its declared. It is restricted to the [same rules](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.syntax.php) as `const` values; it can only be set equal to very simple expressions and values. Instead, to set a static property to be an object, it must be set afterwards.

### Setting it immediately afterwards

Setting the variable immediately after the class is defined, outside of the class, works perfectly (I believe), as shown, giving the static property an initially null value.

```
Foo::$logger = LoggerRegistry::get('general');

class Foo
{
    static $logger;

    public function bar()
    {
        doThing();
        self::$logger->log('');
    }
}
```

You could equivalently have a static method (e.g. `_static_init`) and call it immediately afterwards, which would initialise such static variables.

### Using the autoloader

An alternative is to add to the autoloader a check for some static attribute of the file's class when loading a file with a name matching the class. For example, on loading Foo.php, containing the class `Foo`, the autoloader could check for a static property (e.g. one named logger) and set it (`Foo::$logger = ...`), or could check for a static initialisation method and call it (`Foo::static_init()`).

For example, this might be done like so.

```
$logger = LoggerRegistry::get('general');

spl_autoload_register( function( $class_name ) use ($logger)
{
    $class_path = BASE_PATH . '/' . str_replace('\\', '/', $class_name) . '.php';
    if ( file_exists($class_path) )
    {
        include $class_path;

        if ( property_exists($class_name, 'logger') )
            $class_name::$logger = $logger;
    }
} );
```